# Intent/Start activity starting the wrong activity?

Tags: java, android, instance, start-activity

For some reason, my start activity sends me to the wrong activity( sending me to add task class vs review task class) no error and following in log cat doesn't help me track down the issue. I tried using startActivityForResult(); but that did not help at all and had the same issue. It goes to createTask.class. I need to put more details but I am not sure what else to put, Maybe the put extra and putting two items packed to the instance, but I don't think that would be an issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You Have 0 Tasks"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:text="@string/viewTaskButtonUIMainString"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26999998" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createTaskButtonUIMain"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:text="@string/createTaskButtonUIMainString"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upCommingTasksTextViewUIMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/upCommingTasksTextViewUIMainActivityString"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/upCommingTasksTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upCommingTasksTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextViewUIMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priorityTextViewUIMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewTaskButtonUIMain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dateTextViewUIMainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
/*
HW02
MainActivity.java
 */
package com.example.hw02;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UI Vars
    Button viewTaskButtonUIMain;
    Button createTaskButtonUIMain;
    TextView amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain;
    TextView taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity;
    TextView dateTextViewUIMainActivity;
    TextView priorityTextViewUIMainActivity;
    //Java Vars
    ArrayList<Tasks> taskArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> taskNameList;
    int selectedTask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //UI Vars inst
        viewTaskButtonUIMain = findViewById(R.id.viewTaskButtonUIMain);
        createTaskButtonUIMain = findViewById(R.id.createTaskButtonUIMain);
        amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain = findViewById(R.id.amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain);
        dateTextViewUIMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.dateTextViewUIMainActivity);
        priorityTextViewUIMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.priorityTextViewUIMainActivity);
        taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity);

        //Java Vars inst
        taskArrayList = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
        //create Tasks
        createTaskButtonUIMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent sendArray1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,createTask.class );
                sendArray1.putExtra("reviewActivityArray",taskArrayList);
                startActivity(sendArray1);
            }
        });


        viewTaskButtonUIMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] taskNames = new String[taskArrayList.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i < taskNames.length; i++) {
                    taskNames[i] = taskArrayList.get(i).getTaskName();
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select Task")
                        .setItems(taskNames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Intent taskDelete = new Intent(MainActivity.this, reviewActivity.class );
                                taskDelete.putExtra("catch1", taskArrayList);
                                taskDelete.putExtra("catch2",which);
                                startActivity(taskDelete);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });


        amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain.setText("You have "+ taskArrayList.size() + " tasks");



        //This is for the Create Task
        if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("catch")){
            taskArrayList = (ArrayList<Tasks>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("catch");

            int vartempsize = taskArrayList.size();//delete
            amountOfTasksTextViewUIMain.setText("You have "+ taskArrayList.size() + " tasks");
            Collections.sort(taskArrayList);

            //if the arrayList isn't empty
            if(taskArrayList.isEmpty()==false){
                //change the text
                String tempName = taskArrayList.get(0).getTaskName();
                taskNameTextViewUIMainActivity.setText(tempName);
                dateTextViewUIMainActivity.setText(taskArrayList.get(0).returnDate().toString());
                priorityTextViewUIMainActivity.setText(taskArrayList.get(0).getPrioty());
            }
        }

        //comming from review
        if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("dead")){
            taskArrayList = (ArrayList<Tasks>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dead");
            Collections.sort(taskArrayList);
        }

    }





    private void sortLists(){
        //sorts list
        Collections.sort(taskArrayList);
        //organize the names
        taskNameList.clear();
        //adds all the names in the same order as the taskArrayList
        for (Tasks var : taskArrayList){
            taskNameList.add(var.getTaskName());
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".reviewActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TaskInformationTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/taskInfromationTextViewUIactivityReviewString"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06999999" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nameTextViewUICreateTextString"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/TaskInformationTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TaskInformationTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dateTextViewUIactivityReviewString"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priorityTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/priorityTextViewUIactivityReviewString"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dateTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.07999998" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTaskTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameTextViewUIactivityReview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTaskTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameTaskTextViewUIactivityReview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priorityTaskTextViewUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/priorityTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dateTaskTextViewUIactivityReview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButtonUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="@string/cancleButtonUICreateTaskString"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/priorityTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/priorityTextViewUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.16000003" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButtonUIactivityReview"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="@string/deleteButtonUIactivityReviewString"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cancelButtonUIactivityReview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.58"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancelButtonUIactivityReview" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```py
package com.example.hw02;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class reviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Tasks> taskArrayList;
    int plank;
    Button deleteButtonUIactivityReview;
    Button cancelButtonUIactivityReview;
    TextView nameTaskTextViewUIactivityReview;
    TextView dateTaskTextViewUIactivityReview;
    TextView priorityTaskTextViewUIactivityReview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);
        deleteButtonUIactivityReview  = findViewById(R.id.deleteButtonUIactivityReview);
        cancelButtonUIactivityReview = findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonUIactivityReview);

        deleteButtonUIactivityReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                taskArrayList.remove(plank);
                Intent goHomeDelete = new Intent(reviewActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                goHomeDelete.putExtra("dead",taskArrayList);
                startActivity(goHomeDelete);
            }
        });
        cancelButtonUIactivityReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goHomeSafe = new Intent(reviewActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goHomeSafe);
            }
        });

        if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("catch1")){
            taskArrayList = (ArrayList<Tasks>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("catch1");
            plank = (int)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("catch2");
        }

        nameTaskTextViewUIactivityReview.setText(taskArrayList.get(plank).taskName);
        dateTaskTextViewUIactivityReview.setText(taskArrayList.get(plank).returnDate().toString());
        priorityTaskTextViewUIactivityReview.setText(taskArrayList.get(plank).getPrioty());




        }
    }
```

Comment: you want the intent to go to the  reviewActivity ?

Comment: what is your real problem?

Comment: Yes I need it to go to review activity

Comment: on clicking on which button and what problem persists?

Comment: I click  the viewTaskButtonUIMain which creates a AlertDialog window with all of the choices a user can make. When they select a choice it has to move to reviewActivity.java

Comment: try this code to get intent ** getIntent().getStringExtra("catch1");** try  to print what you got